# if statement returns wrong output JavaScript (Node.js, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, if-statement

I'm trying to add new items in my mongoDB database with the "app.post" in my "Today" list.

this is my root route with the list title - Today.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Item.find({}, (err, foundItems) => {
    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
    }
  });
});
```

Posting a new item in my "Today" list logs the else-statement in my console, even though both logs at the end show "Today".

```
  app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const newItem = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: newItem,
  });

  if (listName === "Today") {
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    console.log("Doesn't Exist");
  }

  console.log(listName);
  console.log("Today");
});
```

Hope this snippet is helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Check the length of listName. If it's "Today", it should be 5. If it's bigger than that, there might be whitespace hiding in the end of the string.

Comment: There is indeed, thank you! listName.length shows me a length of 6 but I can't figure out where the whitespace is hiding. EDIT: I found the whitespace. Thanks again!

Comment: Add a trim() to your listName and you should be fine then.

Comment: It could be a newline character that has zero-width and is hard to detect. You might get these when copying the string from another source (a word processor for example). Use listName.trim() to get rid of it, but you might want to find the origin of the whitespace to do a proper fix.